# How can I write new T-SQL script with ScriptDom and changed columns?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, scriptdom

I would like to build T-SQL parser which will be building new queries for different DBMS with specific rules. First rule which would like to implement is to add to every column name `'` at the beginning and end of column name.

I get code from below link
[SQL, all column names are in brackets, C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34287025/sql-all-column-names-are-in-brackets-c-sharp)

Used Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom;

namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    public class QueryParser
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> Parse(string sqlSelect)
        {
            TSql100Parser parser = new TSql100Parser(false);
            TextReader rd = new StringReader(sqlSelect);
            IList<ParseError> errors;
            var columns = new List<string>();

            var fragments = parser.Parse(rd, out errors);
            var columnVisitor = new SQLVisitor();
            fragments.Accept(columnVisitor);
            columns = new List<string>(columnVisitor.Columns);

            return columns;
        }
    }


    internal class SQLVisitor : TSqlFragmentVisitor
    {
        private List<string> columns = new List<string>();

        private string GetNodeTokenText(TSqlFragment fragment) 
        { 
            StringBuilder tokenText = new StringBuilder(); 
            for (int counter = fragment.FirstTokenIndex; counter <= fragment.LastTokenIndex; counter++) 
            { 
                tokenText.Append(fragment.ScriptTokenStream[counter].Text); 
            }

            return tokenText.ToString(); 
        }


        public override void ExplicitVisit(ColumnReferenceExpression node)
        {
            columns.Add(GetNodeTokenText(node));
        }

        public IEnumerable<string>  Columns {
            get { return columns; }
        }
    } 

    public class Program
    {

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser();
            var columns = queryParser.Parse("SELECT A,[B],C,[D],E FROM T  WHERE isnumeric(col3) = 1 Order by Id desc");
            foreach (var column in columns)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(column);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I do not know how to build a new script which the only difference between old and new one will be column names with `'`.

So the result of below SQL:

```
SELECT A,[B],C,[D],E FROM T  WHERE isnumeric(col3) = 1 Order by [Id] desc
```

should be

```
SELECT A,'B',C,'D',E FROM T WHERE isnumeric(col3) = 1 Order by 'Id' desc
```

Comment: FYI, [don't use `ISNUMERIC`](https://wp.larnu.uk/stop-using-isnumeric-its-probably-wrong/), it's a *terrible* function; it doesn't tell you is the column can be converted to a `numeric` but if the value can be converted to *any* of the numerical data types (and even then, it's not always correct). Switch to using `TRY_CONVERT`/`TRY_CAST`.

Comment: Good luck with that. I don't follow what this will accomplish, I would have assmued you would need to add the appropriate delimiters for the target DBMS.

Comment: Column names with single quotes will just return an unamed column containing a string with the column name. Is that what you actually need? Double quotes is standard SQL. And ISNUMERIC isn't standard SQL anyway

Comment: But anyway TSQL ScriptDom is for generating TSQL not arbitrary SQL grammars

Comment: You'll need to extract the text from the tokens that precede and follow each column to build the new SQL statement.

Comment: @DanGuzman could you help with that ?

Comment: @adam.g,  add the actual code to your question, not as link. I don't have time to write an answer now but maybe later if someone else doesn't answer first.

Comment: Isn't it better to use hibernate or jooq or sql alchemy or EF. Building server-agnostic sql is very complicated and someone else already done this work for you

Answer (score 1):

Below is a refactored version of the code that replaces square bracket enclosures in column identifier references with single quotes and returns the transformed script. This will also replace enclosures in multi-part identifiers.

I implemented the visitor with the `QueryParser` class, inheriting from `TSqlConcreteFragmentVisitor` instead of `TSqlFragmentVisitor`. It's best to use the concrete visitor as the base class unless you need to visit fragments as abstract base types.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom;

namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    public class QueryParser : TSqlConcreteFragmentVisitor
    {

        //column identifiers keyed by FirstTokenIndex
        private Dictionary<int, Identifier> columnIdentifiers = new Dictionary<int, Identifier>();
        private TSqlFragment tsqlScriptFragment;

        public string Parse(string sqlSelect)
        {

            var parser = new TSql160Parser(false);
            var rd = new StringReader(sqlSelect);
            IList<ParseError> errors;
            tsqlScriptFragment = parser.Parse(rd, out errors);
            if(errors.Count > 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"Error(s) parsing SQL script. {errors.Count} errors found.");
            }

            tsqlScriptFragment.Accept(this);

            return getTransformedSqlScript();

        }

        //this is not used in this example but retained if you need it for other use cases        
        private string getNodeTokenText(TSqlFragment fragment)
        {
            StringBuilder tokenText = new StringBuilder();
            for (int counter = fragment.FirstTokenIndex; counter <= fragment.LastTokenIndex; counter++)
            {
                tokenText.Append(fragment.ScriptTokenStream[counter].Text);
            }

            return tokenText.ToString();
        }

        //add identifiers in ColumnReferenceExpression to dictionary upon visit
        public override void ExplicitVisit(ColumnReferenceExpression node)
        {

            foreach(var identifier in node.MultiPartIdentifier.Identifiers)
            {
                this.columnIdentifiers.Add(identifier.FirstTokenIndex, identifier);
            }

        }

        private string getTransformedSqlScript()
        {

            var transformedScript = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < tsqlScriptFragment.ScriptTokenStream.Count; ++i)
            {

                if (columnIdentifiers.ContainsKey(i))
                {
                    //replace square braket enclosures with single quotes, if needed
                    var columnIdentifier = columnIdentifiers[i];
                    var newcolumnIdentifier = columnIdentifier.QuoteType == QuoteType.SquareBracket ? $"'{columnIdentifier.Value}'" : columnIdentifier.Value;
                    transformedScript.Append(newcolumnIdentifier);
                }
                else
                {
                    //keep original script text
                    transformedScript.Append(tsqlScriptFragment.ScriptTokenStream[i].Text);
                }

            }

            return transformedScript.ToString();
        }

    }

    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var queryParser = new QueryParser();
            var transformedScript = queryParser.Parse("SELECT A,[B],T.C,T.[D],E FROM T  WHERE isnumeric(col3) = 1 Order by [Id] desc");

            Console.WriteLine(transformedScript);

        }
    }
}
```